# mPDF - Header for First Page only but Footer for every page

Tags: php, html, pdf, mpdf

I need to set the header for FIRST page only and the footer for every page. Can't figure a way and I've been search for the solution DAYS already. Currently my code goes like this

```
$mpdf=new mPDF();

$mpdf->useOddEven = true;

$mpdf->SetHTMLHeader('<div style="text-align: right;"><img src="var:images" 
width="80px"/></div>', 'O');

$mpdf->SetHTMLFooter('<div style="text-align: left; font-family: Arial, Helvetica,
sans-serif; font-weight: bold;font-size: 7pt; ">Footer</div>');

$html = 'Content';
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$mpdf->Output();
```

I've set the header to Odd however, both header and footer appears on other odd page (3, 5, 7,... page). Is there a way to make the header first page only but the footer appears in every page?

Currently using MPDF5.6

Answer (score 4):

According to the Documentation:
https://mpdf.github.io/reference/mpdf-functions/sethtmlheader.html

The Third Parameter is:

> ```
> write
> If TRUE it forces the Header to be written immediately to the current page. Use if the header is being set after the new page has been added.
> DEFAULT: FALSE
> ```

SO..

```
$mpdf->SetHTMLHeader('<div style="text-align: right;"><img src="var:images" width="80px"/></div>', 'O', true);
$mpdf->SetHTMLHeader('');
$footer = array (
    'L' => array (
      'content' => 'Footer',
      'font-size' => 7,
      'font-style' => 'B',
      'font-family' => 'Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif',
      'color'=>'#000000'
  ),
    'C' => array (
      'content' => '',
      'font-size' => 10,
      'font-style' => 'B',
      'font-family' => 'serif',
      'color'=>'#000000'
    ),
    'R' => array (
      'content' => '',
      'font-size' => 10,
      'font-style' => 'B',
      'font-family' => 'serif',
      'color'=>'#000000'
    ),
'line' => 1,
);
$mpdf->SetFooter($footer);
```

Only the SetFooter Method can set for the footer for both ODD & EVEN pages.